# How to exclude a weaved property from an entity in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, arangodb

I need to globally exclude an AspectJ weaved property from all my persistent entities based on a pattern, i.e. prop name starting with $ajc$instance.

Greetings! I have a question about Spring Data implementation. I have an entity that is enhanced using AspectJ with a dynamic property. The property starts with $ajc$instance and is automatically added to the list of properies. The only solution I found so far was to clone the DefaultArangoConverter class and modify the createEntity() method to add:

```
    if (property.getName().startsWith("ajc$instance$")) {
            
      return;
    }
```

I don't want this property to be taken into account at all and excluding it at the ObjectMapper is too late. I wonder if there is a better way to get this done.

I am relatively new to ArangoDB and its Spring Data implementation. I would appreciate some guidance on it.

Thank you!
Oleg